# Binary to Decimal using recursion in C

Tags: c

I'm new student to this programming , When I use this code to turn binary into decimal, when there's large numbers as input then the output will be negative. Can someone help me fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int deci(int num);
int main()
{
    int bina;
    printf("Enter the Binary number:");
    scanf("%d",&bina);
    printf("The decimal is %d", deci(bina));
    return 0;
}
int deci(int num)
{
    if(num==0) return 0;
    return num%10+2*deci(num/10);
}
```

Comment: Use `unsigned long long`? Also you had better enter a string and convert from that.

Comment: @r3mainer Didi you mean _"Don't use an integer to store the output"_?

Comment: There shouldn't be any decimal involved at all. C does not store numbers in decimal, but in binary, and the appearance of decimal comes from outputting with `%d` format. The reason you have `10`s in the code is becuase you are not inputting a binary number, but a decimal one containing only `0`s and `1`s. So, oddly you are really converting decimal to binary, and not the other way round. So what you should do to enter binary is to input to a string, and build the value from the string. It doesn't need recursion.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Oh, I got this one backwards. Never mind :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much! I used strtoull after saving the number as string. and then used unsigned long long int to read the ull and give the output.

Comment: What is the reason to read the user input with the "%d" format to an int variable? How do you want you your code to handle the input "0815"? I would recommend using `fgets` to read a line of text and parse all '0'  and '1' characters and reject the string if anything else is found.

Comment: Your program works perfectly.  At least on my machine.  Can you explain what do you feed to it and what do you expect?  I tried to give it several binary numbers like `110`  and `1010` and I got answers like `6` or `10`.  What is large numbers for you?  you can give it as much as `111111111` (as you are in a 32 bit machine, so the largest number you can give is that, as a decimal representation of a binary number --- 32 bit ints can accept number upto `2,147,483,647`)

Comment: @LuisColorado I actually wanted to make it work with bigger numbers. Now i'm using the string method to save the input, takes longer numbers now.

Comment: @Maaz, I know that, I tried to answer your question as it was formulated, IMHO you have addressed (and solved) correctly the problem, but didn't get of the waste of more than 3bits/bit in representing a decimal number as binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you take the input as an `int` but an `int` type can't hold the big input values that you are trying to use.

For instance the binary input: `11110000111100011110000` is a much bigger number than the maximum value for an `int`.

Instead of `int` you can use `unsigned long long` which will help you a little. But still it won't work!

If we assume that your input is at max 32 binary numbers (the typical size of unsigned int) and that your `unsigned long long` is 64 bit, the `unsigned long long` will still not be able to handle input like `11110000111100011110000`. So the program will fail.

The solution is to take input as a **string** instead of a number.

It can look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

uint32_t deci_help(char* bina, uint32_t num)
{
    if(*bina == '\0') return num;
    assert(*bina == '0' || *bina == '1');
    return deci_help(bina+1, 2*num + (*bina - '0'));
}

uint32_t deci(char* bina)
{
    return deci_help(bina, 0);
}

int main()
{
    char bina[33];
    printf("Enter the Binary number:");
    scanf("%32s", bina);
    printf("The decimal is %"PRIu32, deci(bina));
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
11111111111111111111111111110101
```

Output:

```
4294967285
```

BTW: Recursion is **not a good solution** for this task but I guess you were required to use recursion. The better solution is a simple for/while loop.

With a loop the function could be:

```
uint32_t deci(char* bina)
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    while (*bina != '\0')
    {
        assert(*bina == '0' || *bina == '1');
        result = 2*result + (*bina - '0');
        ++bina;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have limit too? But anyways. I'll use the string itself as you suggested!. Thank you.

Comment: @Maaz This is limited to 32 bit binary input. If you want to handle 64 bit binary input, change all `uint32_t` to `uint64_t` (and correct array size and printf as well). If you want to handle more than 64 bit, it requires a different program.